# Check string in select option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have created with javascript and I get a result of a string.I get that result on my html code

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

Next,I want when I select for example Red to  check if it is the  the same thing (string), the select option - > **Red** with the string of this code

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

I was trying to do it but I failed.It is not working not even sure ,if I press the submit button I will send the string.

```
<div id="results"></div>
<form method="post" >

  <select >
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="R">Red</option>
    <option value="B">Black</option>
  </select>
  
<input id="results" type="submit" value="results"/>
```

Comment: And where is that JavaScript?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette it's not important the javascript code.The result I get is in that div(<div id="results"></div>) .It gives me a string Black or Red .It depends on.

Comment: Do you have a script for `I want when I select for example Red to check if it is the the same thing`? Or you just want someone to write it for you?

Comment: I tried to do that but I failed ...I want someone to write it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you want to check whether the selected option is equal to the text value of the div `#results`. You can achieve this effect like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var select = $("select");
  $("input[type=\"button\"]").click(function(){
  var text = select.find(":selected").text();
    if(text==$("#results").text()){
      $("#results").html(text+" is equal!");
    }else{
      $("#results").html(text+" is not equal :(");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results">Red</div>
<form method="post" >

  <select >
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="R">Red</option>
    <option value="B">Black</option>
  </select>
  
<input id="results" type="button" value="results"/>
</form>
```

Comment: can you make it display on a table better - cause I have some issues on console through web..can you please do that?

Comment: @maiklef What do you mean "display on a table?"

Comment: I don't like to see it in console ,example I would like to see it on a table the result if it is equal . Red | equal.

Comment: if you see the javascript goes into console log.Instead of console log I would like to display it on html

Comment: @maiklef Completed!

Comment: @maiklef Anytime :)

Answer (score 0):

A form is going to be Sending data somewhere, it would be best to remove the form, leaving the select and button elements. In the button add the code `onclick='myFunction() ;` when the button is clicked it will run the javascript function called `myFunction()`. Also you need to give the select a Id. I'm using selectInput

```
<script>myFunction() { document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = document.getElementById('selectInput').value;} </script>
```

Now when ever the button is pressed it will set the content of the div equal to the value entity in the selected select box option

Comment: thank you a lot ,but I find it easier another another.I appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You lack an action attribute.

```
<form method="post" action="path/to/file">
  <select name="select">
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="R">Red</option>
    <option value="B">Black</option>
  </select>

  <input type="submit" value="Get Results" />
</form>
```

Use a function, and a regular button. No form is needed.

```
<button onclick='func()'></button>
const func = () => {...}
```

Comment: thank you a lot ,but I find it easier another another.I appreciated